# Constraints or rigid body for shoe on pedals?

Tags: constraints, rigid-body-simulation

I'm still learning Blender, so I need a little guidance regarding which methods I need to study next.

I've got a shoe that will operate the pedals of a truck:

[image]

I need to animate the shoe pressing either pedal, and moving from one pedal to the other. (Yes, eventually I'll want to add a leg, but I'll worry about that later!)

The pedals rotate independently around the horizontal axis at the top of the struts. I want to make it so that when I apply the shoe to a pedal, the pedal will rotate in response to the motion of the shoe.

To make this happen, do I need to use constraints? (Remember, I'll need to lift the shoe off one pedal and put it on the other.) Or, should I use rigid body simulation?

(Later, I can add a lattice deformation with shape keys to the shoe if I need to accommodate the contact area between the shoe and the pedal; but I'll only do this if it's visually needed.)

Comment: Definitely constraints (or drivers), a rigid body simulation would be overkill in this case.

Comment: I second constraints. This can easily be done with Transformation constraints.

Comment: OK... So how do I turn constraints on and off so that I don't get *both* pedals going down? And how do I define the constraint so that it's active only when the bottom of the shoe's mesh is colliding with the top of the pedal's mesh?

Comment: @DanBennett looks like Blender Game Engine can solve your problem.

Comment: It depends how much are you willing to work in the rigging phase to make the animation phase easier. A fully automated solution is not easy. Maybe the easiest way is to just animate the shoe and the pedal independently, but in a way that creates the illusion of pushing. But if you do it with constraints, you can turn them off with their influence property.

Comment: I've decided to use a rigid body world for this. It works well, but I do have a problem, which I'll post in a new Question.

Comment: Aha! Already found the answer: Increasing the constraint iterations fixed the Hinge and Fixed constraints I have in the scene.

Comment: In the end, I had to ditch the rigid body world. It was working, but I was getting positional noise that I couldn't eliminate. I played with iteration counts, spring stiffnesses, damping, etc. To no avail. :(   So now I'm just keyframing the position of the pedals as the shoe moves. It's OK, but less flexible.